# End point not displayed, urlTemplating

Tags: spring, spring-boot, springdoc

I use spring boot 3 and springdoc.

In my gradle file I have

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-common:2.0.4'
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.4'
```

I have theses both endpoint

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "nom")
public ResponseEntity<List<PersonDuplicateDto>> findPersonDuplicate(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam String name) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(personService.searchDuplicate(id, name), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<PersonDto> findPersonById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(personService.findPersonById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Actually when swagger-ui.html

I see only the first endpoint, the second one is not displayed

seem to have a workaround with spring fox, need to enableUrlTemplating

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1828

but don't find this options in springdoc